# How do I disable the default window restore animation?

Tags: 11.10, unity

Under Unity in Ubuntu 11.10, the default animation for restoring a minimised window is a kind of swooping zoom. What setting in CompizConfig Settings Manager do I need to change to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be disabled using the CompizConfig Settings Manager, but that also disables the minimization effect.

- Go to the *Animations* plugin,
- Open the *Minimize Animation* tab,
- Double-click the *Zoom* entry in the *Animation Selection* list, and
- Select *None*.

That's it, restore effect should be disabled.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was in there, but couldn't find the right one.